# How to stop tab change from running fragment onCreateView in Andriod

Tags: java, android, tabs

I have three tabs using the implementation below and they perform very well. When tab is changed the proper fragment is load and so on. The problem is that, when i get to the last tab and comeback to the first fragment, its like its oncreateview method is always triggered again running the other codes it in causing duplicates. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

//Activity on the tab is based

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
private int[] tabIcon = {R.drawable.ic_home, R.drawable.ic_message, R.drawable.ic_person};
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
    //Toolbar
    toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //ViewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    //Tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcon[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcon[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcon[2]);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch(tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Home");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Messages");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Profile");
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }


    });
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    myViewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new CategoryFragment(), "Categories");
    myViewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new MessagesFragment(), "Messages");
    myViewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ProfileFragment(), "Profile");
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
}

//View Pager Adapter
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragments, String titles){

        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(titles);
    }

    public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        //return tabTitles.get(position);
        return null;
    }
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

//Main first fragment code
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

```
private DBHandler dbHandler;
private ListView listView;
private ListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Categories> categoriesList = new ArrayList<Categories>();

public CategoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    //Setting up the basic categories
    dbHandler = new DBHandler(view.getContext());

    //Get Categories from database
    final Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getCategories(0);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Categories categories = new Categories();
                categories.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
                categories.set_categoryname(cursor.getString(2));
                categories.set_categoriescaption(cursor.getString(3));
                categoriesList.add(categories);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.categories);

    adapter = new CategoryAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.cursor_row, categoriesList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Integer cid = (int) (long) adapter.getItemId(position);

                    TextView categoryname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cursor);
                    String cname = categoryname.getText().toString();

                    Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), CategoryList.class);
                    i.putExtra("categoryname", cname);
                    i.putExtra("categoryid", cid);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
    );

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

So when i swipe back here from the last tab. OncreateView runs again. How can i handle that and prevent duplicates. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defaults ViewPager retains only 1 page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.So when you swipe to third tab the viepager destroys the first tab in order to retain the second one.

To solve this issue add this line

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

after you set your adapter.
Check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) the documentation for more